# sql dump automatic change

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm looking to automatically change an sql dump (without needing to know the original db name) - so if the SQL Dump says for example...

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mysql` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
```

I want it to automatically scan for all `CREATE DATABASE` lines in the file and append `mysql` to show as `prefix_mysql`

For all `CREATE DATABASE` records in the file - is that possible? - I can find the database names here, but I don't know how to tie it together

```
find . -name \*.sql -type f -exec bash -c '
echo "found $# sql dumps"
for file; do
dbnames=( $(grep -Poe "CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\K[^\`]*" "$file") )

printf "\n          file: %s\n" "$file"
printf "%2s database(s): %s\n" "${#dbnames[*]}" "${dbnames[*]}"

done
> ' 'find-sh' {} +
```

Also tried

```
read -p "enter the cPanel username: " cpuser
cd "/home/$cpuser/public_html"
dbnames=($(grep $sqldump -Poe "CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\K[^\`]*"))
for i in ${dbnames[@]}; do sed -i "s/$i/$cpuser_$i" $sqldump; done
```

However I get;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: `bash` or `sh`? They're not the same.

Comment: Use `sed` rather than `grep`?

Comment: I have tried the above, however, this didn't work - (added to main page)

Comment: Per the bash tag you used - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `sed` search for the pattern itself when substituting, rather than using `grep` to find it.

```
find . -name '*.sql' -exec sed -i "s/\\(CREATE DATABASE [^\`]*\`\\)/\\1${cpuser}_/" {} +
```

Your code doesn't only replace in the `CREATE DATABASE` line, it replaces all occurrences of the database name. Which means if the database name appears in column names, dumped values, etc. these will get the prefix added.

Also, you need to use `${cpuser}` with braces if you want to put a literal `_` after it. Otherwise it looks for a variable named `cpuser_`.

Comment: Hi Barmar - I tried this but I get command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I forgot to escape the backticks. I've testd this, it appears to work now.

Comment: Thank you, I am tryingto do this too - but it isn't working mysql -u root < ${sqldump}

|| The dump is defined as sqldump=$(find . -name \*.sql -type f)

Comment: You can't put multiple files after `<`. Use `cat $sqldump | mysql -u root` to pipe all of them